# Why can't I reference a property in an ICollection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I just want to print the path of some images, that are stored in the `Path` property of `Image` model, but I can't because is an ICollection.

[image]

The following example is possible, because it's not an ICollection

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
```

[image]

That is my controller page

[image]

As you can see, I tried some things hoping to find an answer

When I debug, I can see the properties, I just need the `Path`

[image]

I even already tried doing this

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Image.Select(a => a.Path))
```

But doing this I get a:

```
 InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

Runtime Error

Someone can help me? Thanks in advance

Edit: Product Model code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApp.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(18,2)")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Image> Image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on the last screen shot it looks like `@item.Image` property is itself a collection. You'll need to do another loop over that to pull the properties of each instance in that collection.

Comment: Can you show your Product model code?

Comment: Well, if item.Image is a collection, i.e your product has much images, you should iterate it, displaying path to every image in a collection.

Comment: [mcve] please. Text, not images.

Comment: Hover over the four tags you added. One of them tells you explicitly not to use it. Please remove it.

Comment: @AussieJoe, Product Model code added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to reference an [`ICollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=netcore-3.1) instead of a single string value.

You cannot reference a collection like that, you need to iterate through each item to get it's value.

One way to do that is like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Product)
{
   <tr>
        @foreach (var image in item.Image)
        {
            <td>@image.Path</td>
        }    
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it solved. Can you tell me why using `Product = await _context.Product
            .Include(p => p.Image).ToListAsync();` works, but not when I declare a `public IList<Image> Image { get; set; }` and attribute it `Image = await _context.Image.ToListAsync();` this way? It actually throws `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

Comment: @AlissonFabiano I am going to guess that your Image entity is null in your context, and your Product entity is not null. You will need to debug it to see why _context.Image is null. It could be database mapping is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

Razorview isn't for class Interface and Genneric. You may set path for a `List<string>` new